# Errors coming after I build the App and Emulator show App has stopped

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a android application project using xampp (service.php and mysql database). When I am compiling the application the emulator shows app has stopped. When I saw the run tab the following below errors show up.

How can I solve this issue? I don't know where the error is occurring. I tried running HomeActivity as first screen, in that case app is working fine but when I make MainActivity the first screen it show app has stopped.

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.project.newsapp, PID: 27328
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(309746632bytes) bitmap.
    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
    at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19123)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:785)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:643)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:649)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:757)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2980)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2794)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2347)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

My MainActivity.kt File

```
package com.project.newsapp

import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.project.newsapp.contract.Request
import com.project.newsapp.contract.Response
import com.project.newsapp.network.IRequestContract
import com.project.newsapp.network.NetworkClient
import com.project.newsapp.utils.Constant
import com.project.newsapp.utils.showToast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Callback<Response> {

private val retrofitClient = NetworkClient.getNetworkClient()
private val requestContract = retrofitClient.create(IRequestContract::class.java)
private val progressDialog:ProgressDialog by lazy { ProgressDialog(this) }
private val sharedPreferences:SharedPreferences by lazy { getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE) }
lateinit var userName:String

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...")
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true)

    checkIfUserAlreadyRegistered()

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener {
        userName = edUserName.text.toString().trim().uppercase()
        if(userName.isNullOrEmpty()){
            showToast("Please Enter your Name")
        }else{
            progressDialog.show()
            val request = Request(
                action = Constant.REGISTER_USER,
                userName = userName
            )
            val callResponse = requestContract.makeApiCall(request)
            callResponse.enqueue(this)
        }
    }

    /*btnExit.setOnClickListener {
        finish()
    }*/
}

override fun onFailure(call: Call<Response>, t: Throwable) {
    if(progressDialog.isShowing)
        progressDialog.dismiss()

    showToast("Server is not responding. Please try again later.")
    edUserName.setText("")
}

override fun onResponse(call: Call<Response>, response: retrofit2.Response<Response>) {
    if(progressDialog.isShowing)
        progressDialog.dismiss()

    if(response.body()!=null){
        val serverResponse = response.body()
        if(serverResponse!!.status){
            saveUserToPref(serverResponse.userId,userName)
            Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(Constant.KEY_USER_ID, serverResponse.userId)
                putExtra(Constant.KEY_USER_NAME, userName)
                startActivity(this)
                finish()
            }
        }else{
            showToast(serverResponse.message)
            edUserName.setText("")
        }
    }
    else{
        showToast("Server is not responding. Please try again later.")
        edUserName.setText("")
    }
}

private fun saveUserToPref(userId:String, userName:String){
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putString(Constant.KEY_USER_ID,userId)
    editor.putString(Constant.KEY_USER_NAME,userName)
    editor.commit()
}

private fun checkIfUserAlreadyRegistered(){
    val userId = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.KEY_USER_ID,"invalid user id")
    val userName = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.KEY_USER_NAME,"invalid user name")

    if(!userId.contentEquals("invalid user id")
        && !userName.contentEquals("invalid user name")){
        Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(Constant.KEY_USER_ID, userId)
            putExtra(Constant.KEY_USER_NAME, userName)
            startActivity(this)
            finish()
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: don't spam with irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're doing things that require a `Context`, before you actually have one. You'll have a context by the time `onCreate` runs, but not during construction, where you're doing this:

```
private val progressDialog: ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
private var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)
```

I don't know if the `ProgressDialog` constructor is trying to access the `Context` on the `Activity` you're passing in (because your screenshots cut off the bottom of the stacktrace where the root cause is), but `getSharedPreferences` definitely is. You can't make those calls at construction time

Either make them `lateinit` and initialise them in `onCreate`

```
private lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog
private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)
    ...
}
```

or make them `lazy` so they initialise when you access them, which should be in or after `onCreate`

```
private val progressDialog: ProgressDialog by lazy { ProgressDialog(this) }
private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences by lazy { getSharedPreferences(Constant.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE) }
```

Comment: First of all thanks. I did what you both the solutions but still I am getting error. I delete the pictures and add proper error and also change the code of MainActivity.kt as you said. Can please tell me what is still not right?

Comment: @MrFin now you've got a completely different problem: `Canvas: trying to draw too large(309746632bytes) bitmap` - you're trying to draw a 300MB+ image in an `ImageView`. If you search for "canvas: trying to draw too large" you'll find a bunch of questions and solutions that might work, depending on what you're doing to cause it - otherwise you should post a new question about it